# How to get ViewButton to work in React file using JSON file?

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, button, bulma

I am trying to make a button in a table work to where it displays the correct data. Unfortunately, right now it is displaying data in my Constants table and that it an issue. I want it to display the data from my json file when I click "View Inventory". I will leave some screenshots of my json file, my code for the button onclick, view button, and what displays when I click view button.

I expect for the button onclick to display the data from my json file so id, name, and etc. Here are some screenshots of my code.

`HomePage` where `ViewButton` Code is on line 155:
[image]

JSON file code:
[image]

View Button screenshot:
[image]

View Button Shows Now:
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express for the backend you can get the file in as an api route.

You can do something like this:

const fs = require('fs');

```
app.get('/readJson', (req, res) => {
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file_location, 'utf8'));
res.send(data);
});
```

You can add an action on the ViewButton to call this api and then render the response in the table.

Comment: Where should I put this code at?